# Trying to compare vendor purchase price but the results only display the preferred vendor price

Tags: netsuite

I am trying to compare vendor purchase price and then have it tell me which one listed is the preferred vendor. The problem is with my current formulas, when I run the results it only gives me the vendor price for which one is set to the preferred vendor. I want it to tell me the price that is listed for vendor 1 , vendor 2, and vendor 3, and then a column that says which is currently set as the preferred. Currently, it gives me a zero for the price for that vendor if it is not set as the preferred and only displays the preferred pricing.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Ljx3.png]

You can see in the image what I have tried already.
I also tried replacing vendor with {othervendor} to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

> Currently, it gives me a zero for the price for that vendor if it is
>   not set as the preferred and only displays the preferred pricing.

Would be because of something in the criteria that is restricting the results to only where the vendor and preferred vendor match.

You would need to let the criteria let all rows through and add SUMMARY TYPES in the results to reduce / roll-up the rows.